# Как получить несколько объектов из get response?

Tags: java, api, jackson

Как получить объект из response, если в нем находятся еще вложенные объекты одного класса, количество которых может меняться?

Comment: Можете пример привести? Что приходит, что из этого надо десериализовать, а что нет.

Comment: `еще вложенные объекты одного класса, количество которых может меняться` звучит как список или массив

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать модель в которой будут все возможные объекты. Объявить их как `@Nulluble`, и если они придут там будет значение, в противном случае просто `null`.